# How to convert picture to image.RGBA?

Tags: go

I now have a picture of unclear type, he may be jpeg gif, I want to convert him to image.Image, what should I do?

Below is my code

```
func imageToPng(img image.Image) (image.Image, error) {

    var reader = bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    err := png.Encode(reader, img)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    img, err = png.Decode(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return img, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do n’t want to write him to a file, but convert it to image.image because there are follow-up operations

Comment: Signature of your function `imageToPng()` doesn't make sense to me as it returns `image.Image` and not encoded data. `image.Image` is a data structure that provides mapping between grid of pixels and colors. Conversion to PNG is taking that and encoding it into PNG file format. What you are doing is that you take that data structure, encode is at PNG and then decode it back to same data structure which has nothing to do with PNG. What do you want to do with output of your function?

Comment: What I need is to get the color value of each pixel of the image!
If you do not convert to png, you need a lot of judgment

``` 
switch decode.(type) {
 case *image.RGBA:
 // code
 case *image.RGBA64:
// code
}
```

Unified conversion to color.RGBA or RGB can be better obtained

Comment: @jack Thanks for clarifying your question! Can you also edit it's title and update body with your response above? It might be very helpful to other people with same issue.

Comment: @blami ok!! Thank you for reminding!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following function to convert an image.Image to *image.RGBA.

```
func imageToRGBA(src image.Image) *image.RGBA {

    // No conversion needed if image is an *image.RGBA.
    if dst, ok := src.(*image.RGBA); ok {
        return dst
    }

    // Use the image/draw package to convert to *image.RGBA.
    b := src.Bounds()
    dst := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, b.Dx(), b.Dy()))
    draw.Draw(dst, dst.Bounds(), src, b.Min, draw.Src)
    return dst
}
```

The [draw.Draw](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Draw) function converts an arbitrary image type to the destination image type.